# windows iot stops the UWP application if the network cable is unplugged

Tags: networking, uwp, raspberry-pi, iot

We use the Windows IoT to connect to another application in network with TCPClient. All works now, except one point which confuse us. When we unplug the network cable from our raspberry Pi (I guess version 2) the Startup application with a GUI is immediately stopped. When we plug in the cable back, after a little time the Startup app is started again.

We use VS2017 to build arm UWP app.

Any idea how to prevent stop of application?

Comment: Might be better over at the Raspberry PI SE.

Comment: What do you mean with "Raspberry PI SE"? I do not know it. Is it Linux? If so it is no option.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is the TCPClient in a background task?Please share you code.

Comment: I cannot provide source code, but we use for one connection TCPListener with call AcceptTcpClientAsync and on another we create a TcpClient with:
  m_TCPClient.ConnectAsync(m_HostName, m_TcpPort)
but since we use Task, it is probably in background. Anyway how I would then create a foreground task?

Answer (score 0):

As without your source code,I am not sure what cause your problem.I have tested following pieces codes in raspberry Pi 3, when i unplug the network cable, the application with UI does not stop.In foreground task,asynchronous method is recommend, please reference [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps).

**Server:**

```
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6550);
        tcpListener.Start();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        String data = string.Empty;

        while (true)
        {
            var client = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            var stream = client.GetStream();

            int i = 0;

            // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
            do
            {
                i = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if(i > 0)
                {
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, i);

                    //Display received message
                    txtRServerContent.Text = data;
                }

            } while (i > 0);
        }
```

**Client:**

```
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Parse("10.168.197.66"), 14400);            

        // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
        //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();
        NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        // Buffer to store the response bytes.
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];

        // String to store the response ASCII representation.
        String responseData = String.Empty;

        int count = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            count = await stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            if (count > 0)
            {
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, count);

                //Dispaly responsed message
                txtClientContent.Text = responseData;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look what I can use. Just one question. I believe that also an unhandled exception could be the cause, but I assigned already the UnhandledException event for App. Once I was seeing my msgbox, but not in unplug of Network cable, but it seems my file logger flushs not until app close.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue only occur if debugger is attached. For now this topic is closed.